# Why Does Get-ADObject Not Filter ObjectClass="user" Correctly?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0

## Problem

```
Get-ADObject -Filter {ObjectClass = "User"}
```

Returns both users and computers. The object classes display correctly as "user" or "computer".

```
Get-ADobject -Filter {ObjectClass = "Computer"}
```

Returns only computers.

## Other Observations

```
Get-ADObject "CN=desktop1,CN=Computers,DC=contoso,DC=com" `
| Get-Member -Property ObjectClass
```

Returns

```
TypeName: Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject

Name              MemberType            Definition
----              ----------            ----------
ObjectClass       Property              System.String ObjectClass {get;set;}
```

Furthermore, this returns `False`, as expected:

```
$(Get-ADObject "CN=desktop1,CN=Computers,DC=contoso,DC=com").ObjectClass -eq "User"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Queries with `objectClass=User` return user *and* computer objects, because the computer class is derived from the user class. If you want just user objects, filter for `objectClass=User` *and* `objectCategory=Person`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675881).

Comment: Ah! I had expected them to be exclusive, because I see them both as top schema objects and missed the "subClassof" property of "computer" being equal to "user". I did not realize the association existed. Thank you very much.